# Sharing CoreData between App and Extension

Tags: swift, coredata, extension

Нужно разшарить CoreData между програмой и Extension "today"

В **Target Membership** разшарил саму **CoreData.xcdatamodeld** для **Extension** a так же классы необходимые для работы, но попрежнему CoreData не шарится.

> Как правильно шарить **CoreData** между App и Extension ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле работы на 2-3 часа, хотя изначально кажется что можно решить парой функцией...

Основная затрата времени и сложность - вывести **CoreData** и все классы из проекта во **Framework**

Так же особое внимание необходимо уделить ключу от **App Groups***, его легко потерять а креши при этом не особо информативные. Дерзайте!

Данное решение работает на **Apple watch**, **Push** и **Today Exetation**

***[Рабочие решение тут](http://www.makeandbuild.com/blog/post/watchkit-with-shared-core-data)***